# Screen bind key requires extra Enter (RET) key

Tags: ls, gnu-screen

I was playing around with GNU Screen's configuration and put the following configuration in `~/.screenrc`:

```
bind l eval 'exec ls'
```

So, now when I type `C-a l`, it runs `ls` under the current directory. Everything is fine and dandy till now. But the problem is I have to press extra Enter key to quit the process and drop to the terminal again. How can I avoid the pressing of additional Enter key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `C-a l`, this runs `ls` and displays the output in the current window, regardless of what program is running in the window.

If you do this with a shell running in the window and the shell is displaying its prompt, then the output of `ls` is displayed after the prompt. The shell is not aware of what happened, since `ls` is executed directly by Screen. If you were typing at the prompt, what you typed so far is still there, waiting for you to press Enter. If you press Enter after `C-a l`, that executes the command you've been typing; if you haven't typed anything at the last prompt, that's an empty command, which causes the shell to display a new prompt.

In bash or zsh, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to redisplay the prompt and the current input line.

If you want to avoid doing this, inject a `^L` into the application running inside screen, in the hope that it's a shell displaying a prompt. You need to invoke a shell explicitly since you want to run multiple commands. You need to pass `!` as *fdpat* as otherwise the `^L` doesn't go to the shell.

```
bind l exec ! sh -c 'ls /; screen -X stuff ^L'
```

This command is not very useful because it always runs `ls` in Screen's current directory, which does not change when you change directories in the shell. If you want a key to run `ls` from the shell, in the shell's current directory, make a shell binding, not a Screen binding.